# QSortFilterProxyModel and dynamic sort

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I'm using a class that inherit `QSortFilterProxyModel` to only do sorting of rows in a table view.

I've enabled `dynamicSort` to make sure that my view stays sorted even when I load the model or add rows (I've checked that either `modelReset()` or `rowsInserted()` are emitted properly by my model).

But for some reason, my rows are not kept sorted.

Is there something specific to do to enable dynamic sorting?

Is just not what `setDynamicSortFilter` does at all?

Is there a way to manually call sort upon emission of these signals? (every time I try to do it, I get only invalid variants from the model's `data()`, judging by the source, the signal is emitted before the `QSortFilterProxyModel` has finished setting things up again)

Anyway, any help is welcomed to try figuring out how this is supposed to work, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From `dynamicSortFilter` documentation:

> Note that you should not update the source model through the proxy model when dynamicSortFilter is true. For instance, if you set the proxy model on a QComboBox, then **using functions that update the model, e.g., addItem(), will not work as expected**. An **alternative is to set dynamicSortFilter to false and call sort()** after adding items to the QComboBox.

*Is there a way to manually call sort upon emission of these signals? (every time I try to do it, I get only invalid variants from the model's data(), judging by the source, the signal is emitted before the QSortFilterProxyModel has finished setting things up again)*

I think if you will set `dynamicSortFilter` to `false` then your manual calls to `sort` will not (badly) intercept with `QSortFilterProxyModel`'s internal updates. At least I can tell you that this is what I am doing in a similar scenario and it works for me fine.

Comment: The thing is, I don't modify it through the proxy model, but much like you'd call `appendRow` on a `QStandardItemModel`, so it should work in theory.


Maybe something is wrong with my source model...


Otherwise, when I try to manually sort on the various signals after modification, all the QVariants returned by `data()` are invalid for some reason...